# Intellij-idea: auto-repetition of letter keys

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm

Using Intellij-Idea 12 on OS X, I have a strange problem: when I keep a letter ([a-z]) key pressed in the editor, the key stroke does not repeat. This is unfortunately a problem since I would like to use the vim plug-in, and to use the keys h,j,k,l to move the cursor around.

Other, non-letter keys do produce repetition when kept pressed. On Ubuntu 12.04 I don't encounter this problem either.

Is this any option thing? Anyone know where to set preferences of key stroke repetition?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a [system preference](http://lifehacker.com/5826055/make-your-keyboard-keys-repeat-properly-when-held-down-in-mac-os-x-lion) not specific to Intellij IDEA:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Comment: @danslee's solution is much more graceful. Rewrite ApplePressAndHoldEnabled only for IntelliJ. As for me I really like how osx's key repeat (actually 'key don't repeat') works. It effectively prevents from double letter typing in many cases.

Comment: FYI I just installed IdeaVim and the popup says "You can do it manually by running `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled 0`"

Comment: This worked. 
 macOS silicon

Answer (score 44):

You can change also be more specific and change the behavior for only IntelliJ with the following command. The -g option in the above solution changes it for all applications.

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

For the 14.x community edition, you may need to use a different URI:

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij.ce ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

This works for MacOSX 10.10 Yosemite and IntelliJ 13.1.6

Comment: This didn't seem to work with Intellij CE 14.0.3 on OSX 10.10.2

Comment: Did it error out? Or was there no effect? You _might_ need to restart your machine for the change to take effect, but I don't recall having to do that. Also, check to see if the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.jetbrains.intellij.plist has been updated. It might not work with the app running.

Comment: Running both of those lines with IDEA closed doesn't emit an error, and doesn't prevent PressAndHold from being enabled in the editor. Is there a different URI for newer versions of the editor?

Comment: @Neil, you need to read CFBundleIdentifier in from your `/Applications/<IntelliJ IDEA NN.app>/ContentsInfo.plist`. For release versions it is `com.jetbrains.intellij`. @danslee 's solution really works.

Comment: For Android Studio and other Intellij derivatives, see https://gist.github.com/lsd/1e1826907ab7e49c536a

Comment: Second item (the one attributed to the 14.x community) works great for Mac OS Mojave and RubyMine.

Comment: If this doesn't work on its own, you may need to delete the global setting using: `defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002771679/comments/360000345459)

Comment: Worked for me, thank you. BTW, "in the above solution" isn't a good match for SO, since what's above today may not be above tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on macos 10.12.6 using PyCharm Pro 2017.3, one of JetBrains products.
Using danslee and Dao answers, I came up with (replace PyCharm by the name of the application you are using):

1. Quit the JetBrains application,
2. Find the name of the parameter that controls the key repetition by editing the file `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/Info.plist` and looking for the value of the key `CFBundleIdentifier`. This is the parameter I found:
   **com.jetbrains.pycharm**, it might be different for you,
3. Set the parameter found to the desired value: `$ defaults write com.jetbrains.pycharm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`. true will set auto-repeat, false will set no auto-repeat,
4. You can check the value of the parameter by doing this: `$ defaults read > defaults_read.txt` and look for 'ApplePressAndHoldEnabled' in defaults_read.txt,
5. Run the application and check.

Comment: It's counter-intuitive but if you want to enable auto-repeat the bool should be set to false not true. `defaults write com.jetbrains.pycharm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`. This worked for me in PyCharm.

Comment: The answer is imprecise, because the true and false values do the opposite of what is stated (as @Jesse explained in the comment), but the process described is very useful indeed, because can be reused in many different occasions, so thank you @baz65!

Answer (score 0):

for me, I don't want to mess up the global config so I applied only specific application.
In my case, I'm using Goland (com.jetbrains.goland), so I run below command-line in MacOSX terminal:

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.goland ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Now I can press-and-hold the Vim motion keys as normal in Goland.