# IntelliJ key repeating idea.vim

Tags: vim, intellij-13

I just installed *IntelliJ CE* and *IdeaVim* plugin.

One small popup asked about key repeating and if I want to make it enabled. But I just clicked "no" without knowing what it is asking about clearly.
But it was about the moving keys: <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>.

***I cannot hold down these keys to move my cursor continuously.***
I've tried to revert this setting but no luck.

Most answers are either
`defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij.ce ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`
or
`defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`,
but no changes.

I am on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and IntelliJ IDEA CE 2016.2.4

Comment: Why go through the hassle of installing a "vim plugin" in your IDE if you don't want to take advantage of advanced Vim motions?

Comment: @romainl what do you mean by "advanced vim motions"? am I missing something?

Comment: Holding `hjkl` down is exactly the same as holding the cursor keys down. If you only use `hjkl` there's no point installing a "vim plugin".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij-idea: auto-repetition of letter keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107321/intellij-idea-auto-repetition-of-letter-keys)

Comment: @romainl You seem to assume Vim is only about navigating, and that OP only uses Vim for navigation.

Comment: if you are confused what `Do you want to enable repeating keys in Mac OS X on press and hold?` means it means if you hold a key if it should keep pressing it automatically for you. I always expect that behaviour and can't think of a time it's not doing that so I'd suggest pressing `yes`. If you are to late see answers bellow.

Comment: Also, I think that having the navigation right in your home row is still a big improvement over having to move your hand to some random place depending on the keyboard - even if you use them rather naively...

Answer (score 139):

it turns out that I need to type this in the mac terminal:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

This is not related with any of vim, intelliJ, etc.
It seems that Mac wants to support accent characters by holding the key.

Comment: If it's still not working, you should press `Command+Q` to quit IntelliJ first.

Comment: FYI I just installed IdeaVim and the popup says "You can do it manually by running `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled 0`"

Comment: After months of pain and suffering, I cannot take it anymore. I had to find a way, and the above tip worked! Thank you so very much!!

Comment: @aaronpenne's comment worked, not the answer. You should make yours an answer.

Comment: @Chethan bandi's solution is best if you want this change to only apply to your IDE, not your whole system

Answer (score 93):

you can enable key repeating per application

for Intellij Ultimate edition

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

for Intellij community edition

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij.ce ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

ref https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206845385-FYI-for-Lion-users-who-use-IdeaVIM

Comment: This answer is proper solution since I often don't need this feature when I'm not working in IDE. But how could I find the app name for this command?

Comment: If you're using PyCharm: `defaults write com.jetbrains.pycharm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Comment: You can type `defaults write com.jetbrains.` in the terminal and then hit the tab to auto-complete. This gave me the following for webstorm: `defaults write com.jetbrains.WebStorm`

Answer (score 8):

@aaronpenne's 2020 comment is too useful to be just a comment. His was the only suggestion that worked:

> FYI I just installed IdeaVim and the popup says "You can do it
> manually by running defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled 0"

Comment: This worked for me. Remember to restart the IDE after running the command for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already set the global value with the `defaults write -g` command (or JetBrains did it for you), it may be necessary to delete the global default before you can use an application-specific default as noted in [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1408110/set-applepressandholdenabled-for-one-specific-application).

```
defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled
```

After I did that and set an application-specific value for RubyMine...

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.rubymine ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

...I could use IdeaVim in RubyMine and still use the press and hold accent dialog in all other applications.

Comment: Thanks for this, although to get key repeat to work as I desired in RubyMine I set it to false rather than true: `defaults write com.jetbrains.rubymine ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`, then restarted RubyMine.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone else was confused what the message from pycharm meant, but lets read it first:

```
Do you want to enable repeating keys in Mac OS X on press and hold?
```

what it means is that if you keep pressing the same key it is as if it is pressing it many times (the expected behaviour). That is all.

I might not be a vim expert but I personally wouldn't want the keyboard to act different from what I am used to so I suggest to press `yes`.

If you are too late and can't fix it do what the other answers suggest e.g.

for Intellij Ultimate edition

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

for Intellij community edition

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij.ce ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this gist for various different Jetbrains IDEs:

Credits go to this: https://gist.github.com/lsd/1e1826907ab7e49c536a

```
    Community Edition IntelliJ: - defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij.ce ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
    Ultimate Edition IntelliJ: defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
    AppCode: defaults write com.jetbrains.AppCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
    PyCharm: defaults write com.jetbrains.PyCharm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
    Android Studio: defaults write com.google.android.studio ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
    WebStorm: defaults write com.jetbrains.WebStorm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false *
    RubyMine: defaults write com.jetbrains.RubyMine ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false *
```

Answer (score 0):

If this command doesn't work `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Use this -->
`defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Restart the app you're using like re-open the vs code etc... and it should be working.

To enable back, set to `true` again and
you're good to go.

Credits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVUwif3DWuU